# asp.net mvc jsonresult block external use

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, jsonresult

Is it possible to block any other use of json result and allow just requests from my application ?
when we use something like this:

```
Json(q, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

it allow all requests from anywhere.is there any authentication exist to check where request is from ?

Comment: btw.. it shows you only have a 33% question answer rate. I'd mark some of your older questions as answered so people are more likely to help you in the future : )

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean:

How to allow only AJAX requests?

If so, view the following blog post.  It describes creating a reusable filter:

[AjaxOnly attribute](http://helios.ca/2009/05/27/aspnet-mvc-action-filter-ajax-only-attribute/)

The code seems quite simple, but I haven't used it myself:

```
public class AjaxOnlyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute  
{  
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)  
    {  
        if(!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())  
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/error/404");  
    }  

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)  
    {  

    }  
}
```

That you can then apply to controllers and actions:

```
[AjaxOnly]  
public ActionResult AjaxActionMethod()  
{  
    //....  
}
```

The filter code presumes the existence of an action on some controller that can be reached by the following route:

```
/error/404
```

As a result, I have amended the code, and produced an easy way of adding an arbitrary error route (with a default value of "/error/404"):

```
public class AjaxOnlyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public AjaxOnlyAttribute(){}

    public AjaxOnlyAttribute(string ErrorRoute)
    {
        this.ErrorRoute = ErrorRoute;
    }

    string errorRoute = "/Error/404"; // default route
    public string ErrorRoute 
    {
        get { return errorRoute; }
        set { errorRoute = value; }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(this.ErrorRoute); //
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

    }
}
```

This can now be used as follows:

```
[AjaxOnly(ErrorRoute = "/MyArbitraryRoute/MyArbitraryParameter")
public ActionResult AjaxActionMethod()
{
   //....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the [Authorize] attribute to your methods or controllers that you want to protect. You can specify the group membership and a login will be required.

Comment: I think he means stopping a request that isn't an ajax request, but not clear from the text.

Comment: Ya but the op references authentication?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a method to be callable by your own application, change the method declaration from public to internal.  This will limit the scope of the method to calls from within your application.